Error: "1824 bytes of body are still expected" while cloning repository from GitHub
I'm encountering an issue while trying to clone a Git repository from GitHub. When I run the git clone command, I consistently receive the following error message:
1824 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

Checking my network connection
Increasing the buffer size using git config
Cloning via HTTPS instead of SSH
Checking the size of the repository
Ensuring I have enough disk space

However, none of these solutions have resolved the issue. I'm not sure what else to try. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Any suggestions for further troubleshooting or resolution would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Interesting, I had a similar problem two days ago. I ended up using the download as zip function ti get the repo.

What OS and version of Git are you using?  Are you using any sort of proxy, including a non-default antivirus or firewall, TLS MITM device, or monitoring software?

It looks like you're encountering a common error when fetching or cloning large Git repositories. This issue often happens due to network limitations or buffer size constraints in Git.
Here are a few steps that might help:
1. Increase Git’s Buffer Size
Git can struggle with large repositories if the buffer size is too low. You can try increasing the buffer size to handle more data:
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

This sets the buffer to 500 MB. If you still see issues, you can try even larger values.
2. Switch to HTTP/1.1
Sometimes, the HTTP/2 protocol can be finicky with large transfers. Switching to HTTP/1.1 can help avoid certain issues:
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1

This tells Git to use HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2, which can improve compatibility in some cases.
3. Try a Shallow Clone or Fetch
If you don’t need the entire history, you can fetch just the latest commits using a shallow clone. This can reduce the amount of data being transferred:
git fetch --depth=1

Or, if you’re cloning for the first time:
git clone --depth=1 <repository_url>

4. Check Your Network Connection
Sometimes, these errors happen because of unstable network connections. Switching to a wired connection or trying a different network can help if you're on Wi-Fi.
5. Restart the Git Daemon (If You Have Server Access)
If you’re working with a self-hosted Git server, try restarting the Git daemon, as server-side issues can sometimes cause unexpected disconnects.

git config --global http.postBuffer 52428800
working like a charm!!

Try these also,
Clear Git Cache:
Run the git config --global --unset http.sslVerify command to clear the Git cache and re-establish a clean connection.
Reduce Packet Size:
Try reducing the packet size using git config pack.windowSize 1024
Disable Compression:
git config --global core.compression 0

for me the accepted solution didn't work, with 500mb 1gb 2gb 100mb.
I used this contraption:
# 100MB
git config --global http.postBuffer 104857600
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
git config --global core.compression 0
git config --global pack.window 10
git config --global pack.depth 50
git config --global pack.windowSize 10m
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit 2m
git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0
git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 99999
git config --global http.keepAlive true

echo -e "${GREEN}INIT REPO${PLAIN}" ;
repo init -u $HALIUM_REPO -b "halium-$HALIUM_VERSION" --depth=1 --no-clone-bundle;

echo -e "${GREEN}SYNC START. This can take a very long time${PLAIN}" ;
repo sync -c --jobs=$JOBS --no-tags --force-sync --no-clone-bundle --optimized-fetch --prune;
repo sync -c --jobs=$JOBS --no-tags --force-sync --no-clone-bundle --optimized-fetch --prune;

Also changed SSH config just in case(this is from dockerfile):
# Configure SSH client for Git
RUN mkdir -p /home/ubpuser/.ssh && \
    echo "Host *\n\
    ServerAliveInterval 60\n\
    ServerAliveCountMax 10000\n\
    ConnectTimeout 300" > /home/ubpuser/.ssh/config \
    && chmod 600 /home/ubpuser/.ssh/config \
    && chown -R ubpuser:ubpuser /home/ubpuser/.ssh


its a big big repo alright xD
